# read in from a text file and split to two string to be able to pass to

Tags: java

This text file below is a collection of what are a Person object... which the person object has the name and phone number

> jill nim # 9090092323
>   alladin  # 4243535345
>   Defy duck # 4354656575

I am trying to restore this file for the program to use,  but i dont know how to split these strings so i can pass to person instance

`Person s = new Person( String Name, String phonenumber);`

how do i pass the those names and number to make new instance of person.

```
   public void restore(String fileName) {
       // TODO : implement this method.
       // restore bst from a file, if file exists.
       // do nothing, otherwise.
       File fichier = new File(fileName);
            if (fichier.exists())

                try {
                    Scanner n = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

                        while(n.hasNextLine()){     
                            Person s = new Person( n.nextLine(), n.next(pattern));
                        }       
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: If it's in the format that you specified, I suggest that you not use `.split()`.  I just don't see a reason to do it for the case when you only need to separate two tokens.  Might as well use `.substring()` with `indexOf()` instead.

Comment: thank you i took your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `split()`, but it's completely unnecessary for this situation.  In your case, you could just use `.substring()` and `indexOf()`, here's how you would do it:

```
String fromFile = "jill nim # 9090092323";
Person s = new Person(fromFile.substring(0, fromFile.indexOf('#') -1), 
                      fromFile.substring(fromfile.indexOf('#') + 2);
```

Using `.split()` not only creates an array, but also creates a `Pattern` object, both of which are unnecessary.

Comment: What makes split unnecessary? Is there a performance trade off vs using a combination of substring and indexOf?

Comment: @Shobit Why would you want to use extra space when you don't have to?

Comment: @Shobit Besides the array, you're creating a new `Pattern` object, unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method in the String class.

Split your `nextLine()` with "#" i.e. `nextLine().split("#")` to get an array of Strings where your `array[0]` will be the name, and `array[1]` will be the phone number. You can then call your constructor `new Person(array[0].trim(), array[1].trim())` (the trim is to get rid of any extra spaces after splitting)

Answer (score 2):

user **StringTokenizer** for you case like:

```
String foo = "foo # 1234";

StringTokenizer sr =  new StringTokenizer(foo,"#");

while(sr.hasMoreElements())
{
System.out.println(sr.nextElement());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `split("#");`

```
String line = line.nextLine();

String[] tokens = line.split("#");

String name = tokens[0].trim();

String phone = tokens[1].trim();

Person s = new Person(name, phone);
```